# Visual studio merge tool with Xaml.cs files

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I am busy merging my DEV branch back to production for the first time since implementing branching, naturally there are some conflicts that I have to resolve.

My issues is that with .cs and .xaml files, I am offered a "Merge Changes in Merge Tool" option, which is very convenient:

[image]

But with .xaml.cs files this option is not offered. Is there a setting I need to change or workaround I can try?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that both files changed *significantly* enough to warrant a user merge at the same time? It could be that the cs file either did not change or didn't change enough to be presented with  a merge option.

Comment: Yes, most files contains a large amount of changes and no "Merge Tool" option is available.

Comment: I have noticed that TFS is smarter than GIT when having to do user merges. I would take the target branch change and then verify in the TFS history that the file is where it is needed.

Comment: @ChrisjanLodewyks Have you give a try with my method in below answer which will fix the issue?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT this was not quite the solution that I was looking for, seeing that I wanted to merge the target and source branches, if I took only the target branch I would have lost changes made in the source branch. I ended up doing a manual merge.

Comment: @ChrisjanLodewyks  Thanks for the sharing, which I mean in the answer is not simply take target or source version. It's just [Resolve Team Foundation Version Control conflicts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/resolve-team-foundation-version-control-conflicts), either **AutoResolve all conflicts** or **Manually resolve a single conflict**. In your situation, you will need to manually resolve the conflict first. Doing a manual merge is also a good   solution, you could also add an answer and mark it which will  help others in this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and screenshot of `.xaml.cs` file, seems that you get conflicts when you do the merge operation. You should **first resolve these conflicts**. If you are not sure which version you should take, you can right-click the conflict, and click Compare, and then take either the target or source version based on your requirement.

**After you resolved the conflicts, you can then do the merge operation.**  Then the *Merge Changes in Merge Tool* and *AutoMerge* option will appear.